# Alternative to JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

It works, but I need an alternative to the JOptionPane. This is a homework assignment and we are not allowed to use JOptionPane. Here is what I have, which works, it just isn't what the instructor wants.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class calc extends JApplet {

    double sum;
    double product;
    double difference;
    double quotient;

    public void init() {
        String firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
        String secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");
        String thirdNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the third number");
        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber);
        double number2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        double number3 = Double.parseDouble(thirdNumber);
        sum = number1 + number2 + number3;
        product = number1 * number2 * number3;
        difference = number1 - number2 - number3;
        quotient = number1 % number2 % number3;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(15, 10, 270, 60);
        g.drawString("Sum "+sum, 25, 25);
        g.drawString("Product "+product, 25, 35);
        g.drawString("Difference "+difference, 25, 45);
        g.drawString("Quotient "+quotient, 25, 55);
    }
}
```

Comment: Schools, always 10 years late in IT...

Comment: It would help if you described what the goal of the exercise is.

Comment: `Java Swing`---`JLabel`,`JTextField`,`JButton`,etc...

Comment: What @Guillaume said. For example, if the assignment can be a console application, then ChemDiesel's answer may be acceptable. If the assignment must be an applet, the Chem's answer is almost useless.

Comment: The purpose is to have a window ask for input and then to output into another window. The problem is that I missed 2 classes due to falling very ill and now im having to play catch up. The only catch is that we cant use JOptionPane, I assume to make sure we can do it the long way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Scanner method and also initialize your variables as doubles so that you don't need to unnecessarily parse strings. Try something like this:

```
public void init() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first number");        
        double number1 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        double number2 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the third number");
        double number3 = input.nextDouble();

        sum = number1 + number2 + number3;
        product = number1 * number2 * number3;
        difference = number1 - number2 - number3;
        quotient = number1 % number2 % number3;
    }
```

Then to display without JOptionPane, you would use a line similar to this:

```
System.out.println("Quotient is " + quotient);
```

And remember to import as necessary!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Some additional clarity in regards to the assignment would make this question much easier to answer, but that is my best guess based on the available information. I assumed the only reason your teacher wouldn't allow you to use JOptionPane is because it hasn't been covered in the course yet, and as JOptionPane is taught relatively early in most Computer Science programs, I would guess the Scanner method is likely what your teacher is looking for. If you've already covered the Scanner method, try looking into the InputStreamReader method. Hope this helps ;)